# How to remove space between a vertex and an edge in TIKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have the following code to get a graph which contains two nodes $v_1$ and $v_2$ and an edge between $v_1$ and $v_2$.

```
    \tikzstyle{place}=[circle,minimum size=1mm,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,fill=black,thick]    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,auto]
            \node[place,label=above:$v_1$] (v1) at (0,0) {};
            \node[place,label=above:$v_2$] (v2) at (1,0) {};
            
            \draw [-] (v1) -- (v2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

The image it gives is as follows: [image] 
But we can see that there is a space between the edge and vertex $v_2$, how to remove it?

Comment: Do not use `shorten >`. -also do not use `\tikzstyle`

Comment: @hpekristiansen why?

Comment: @AJ Because it shortens all paths at their end.

Comment: :) okay thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
place/.style={circle, minimum size=1mm,
inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, fill
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[place, label=above:$v_1$] (v1) at (0,0) {};
\node[place, label=above:$v_2$] (v2) at (1,0) {};
\draw (v1) -- (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two nodes with line between them]